# Property 'isIP' does not exist on type 'typeof import("...@types/validator/index")'

Tags: typescript, validator.js

I recently upgraded TypeScript to version 5.2.2 and modified my tsconfig.json file a bit (set module/moduleResolution to "nodenext") and am now getting this error, which didn't previously occur:

```
error TS2339: Property 'isIP' does not exist on type 'typeof import(".../node_modules/@types/validator/index")'.
```

Here's the file:

```js
// ./src/valid.ts
import validator from "validator";

console.log(validator.isIP("12312"));
```

`validator` is npm intalled.

My ts config:

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": [
    "build",
    "data",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./build"
  }
}
```

```js
// ../../tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "lib": [
      "es2022"
    ],
    "types": [
      "vitest/importMeta"
    ],
    "module": "nodenext",
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "composite": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true
  }
}
```

Reproduced in this repository: https://github.com/olalonde/tsbug